# Getting document version back after update in Solr5

Tags: solr, solrj, solr5

Is there a way I can get the version of a document back in update response after adding or updating the document via Solrj 5.2.1? I don't want to make one more extra call getById to get the version. Can I somehow get the version in the Update response itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the discussion I had in solr mailing list. The version number can be obtained in update response by setting `versions=true` flag in each update requests. This is described [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Updating+Parts+of+Documents#UpdatingPartsofDocuments-OptimisticConcurrency) towards the end.

In SolrJ this can be set as follows:-
`UpdateRequest().getParam().add("versions","true")`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Realtime Get handler (in the default comfiguration it answers to /get requests). Just pass the document id as input parameter.

Comment: I was thinking if it is possible to get the version without making one more extra call getById. Can I get that as part of the update response when I am updating or adding a new document?

Comment: Mmmm no I don't think it is possible